# How to pass date value created by DatePicker to a mvc 5 controller with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, jquery-ui, datetime, get

I have an activity session page. Each activity have a datetime (dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss). I'm trying to create a sort filter with a start date and a end date to see all's activities between theses dates. For that I have created two textbox with a JqueryUI datepicker. I have created also the method in my controller, and the JS script for passing the data.

My problem is to pass date to the controller. It's not working, I have an empty value when I try to use it in the controller method. I have tried using `Datetime?` in DateFilter, it's working to get the values, but I can't use `AddDays` after that.

Could you tell me If I need to use `toISOString' and how ?

JS script :

```
$("#btndatefilter").click(function () {
    var startdate = $('#datestart').val();
    var enddate = $('#dateend').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AuditActivities/FilterByDate",
        type: "GET",
        data: { dateFilter: { StartDate: startdate, EndDate: enddate } },
    })
    .done(function (auditActivity) {
        $("#res").html(auditActivity);
    });
});
```

Controler

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FilterByDate(DateFilter dateFilter)
    {
        DateTime endperiod = dateFilter.EndDate.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

        string returnpartial = "";
        var auditActivity = db.AuditActivity.Include(a => a.Pc).Include(a => a.Activity).Include(a => a.Users);

        auditActivity = auditActivity.Where(a => a.Date > dateFilter.StartDate && a.Date < endperiod).OrderBy(a => a.Date);
        returnpartial = "Indexactivityuser";
        return PartialView(returnpartial, auditActivity.ToList());
    }
```

Data class

```
public class DateFilter
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method and not `val()` then the variables `startdate` and `enddate` are of type date. Then 
use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). HTH

```
$(function() {
    $("#datestart").datepicker();
    $("#dateend").datepicker();

    $("#btndatefilter").click(function() {
        var startdate = $('#datestart').datepicker('getDate');
        var enddate = $('#dateend').datepicker('getDate');
        var dateFilter = 
        { StartDate: startdate.toISOString(), EndDate: enddate.toISOString() };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("FilterByDate", "AuditActivities")", 
            type: "GET",
            data: dateFilter
        })
        .done(function(auditActivity) {
            $("#res").html(auditActivity);
        });
    });
});
```

---

Or you could pass the `val()` of the `datepicker` to the controller and parse the strings there. To do this specify the format of the `datepicker`.

```
$("#datestart").datepicker({dateFormat:  "yy-mm-dd"});
```

Model has now `string` properties

```
public class DateFilterModel
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And in controller parse the strings by expected format

```
// try { ...
int[] startInfo = dateFilter.StartDate.Split('-').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
DateTime start = new DateTime(startInfo[0], startInfo[1], startInfo[2]);
```

For `yyyy-MM-dd` it worked with `ParseExact()` for me as well.

```
string startInfo = dateFilter.StartDate;
DateTime start= DateTime.ParseExact(
    startInfo, 
    "yyyy-MM-dd", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you again, It will be very usefull If I have to deal with different date format (like dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy).

Comment: toISOString() is making the date one day off.